# pyarrow の orcwriter クラスの使い方

Tags: python

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.orc.ORCWriter.html#pyarrow.orc.ORCWriter
こちらのモジュールを使って AWS Athena で読めるカラムナー形式のファイルを作りたいのですが使い方がわかりません

```
import pyarrow
orc_writer = pyarrow.orc.ORCWriter('test.orc')
```

とかいただけでも
`AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'orc'`
となってそもそもモジュールのクラスすら見つけることができません

---

```
pip list | grep pyarrow
pyarrow             7.0.0
```

となるので入ってるモジュールとみてるドキュメントバージョンは一致しているとおもうのですが...

Comment: 自分はあくまで `AttributeError` について回答したつもりなので、追記で質問内容が変わってきている (というより "使い方" という聞き方だと範囲が曖昧な) 気がします。 / 参考: [質問の回答を受けて別の質問を追加したい時はどうしたら良い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3345)

Comment: `ORCWriter` 前提ですか？

Comment: pyorc を使って orc を使っていたんですが時間もメモリもかかってしまうので試しに別のライブラリを使ってみようという感じです。やりたいのは時間と共に増え続ける大量のJSONファイルからSQLで分析できるテーブルを低コストで作りたいです。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/86652/pyarrow-%e3%81%ae-orcwriter-%e3%81%ae%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e6%96%b9　こちらに質問の続きを移動しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の import 文を追加してみてください。

```py
import pyarrow.orc
```

参考:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68415793/2322778